# Consulta dinámica usando LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Ocupo aplicar algunos filtros en una aplicación, por lo cual necesito usar consultas dinámicas usando *Linq*, los filtros están con unos *selects* entonces cuando cambie la opción del *select* se debe de aplicar en la consulta.

Esto ya lo tengo hecho usando *sql* de la siguiente forma:

```
var consulta = "SELECT ID_Request, ID_Status, RequestDate FROM REQUEST WHERE ID_Applicant  =  '" + ID_Applicant + "'";

if (ID_Request != "") {
    consulta = consulta + " AND ID_Request = '" + ID_Request + "'";
}

if (ID_Company != "all") {
    consulta = consulta + " AND ID_Company = '" + ID_Company + "'";
}

consulta = consulta + " ORDER BY RequestDate DESC;";
```

Y ya solo ejecuto la consulta, pero ahora esto lo ocupo hacer usando Linq y no encuentro una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Añade algún fragmento de código que hayas probado usando Linq o cualquier cosa con la que te podamos ayudar, ya que la información que nos proporcionas es poca.

Comment: Osea, quieres traducir ese sql a Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los querys no se ejecutan al momento de ser creados sino que son expresiones que se van a armando dinámicamente y pueden ser modificadas antes de su ejecución por lo que podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
var consulta = db.Request.Where(x => x.ID_Applicant == ID_Applicant);

if (ID_Request != "") {
    consulta = consulta.Where(x => x.ID_Request == ID_Request);
}

if (ID_Company != "all") {
    consulta = consulta.Where(x => x.ID_Company == ID_Company);
}

consulta = consulta
    .OrderByDescending(x =>.RequestDate)
    .Select(x => new { x.ID_Request, x.ID_Status, x.RequestDate });
```

Cabe desatacar los `Where()` no se reemplazan entre si, sino que van agregando nuevas condiciones que también deberán ser cumplidas (lo que en la práctica significa lo mismo que el `AND`)

Answer (score 0):

Esta seria la forma de hacerlo en Linq. Recuerda ejecutar `ToList()` al final, no en cada `Where` ya que esto materializaria en memoria la consulta sql:

```
 var requests = dbContext.Request.Where(x=>x.ID_Applicant ==ID_Applicant);

if (ID_Request != "") {
    requests  = requests.Where(x=>x.ID_Request  == ID_Request);
}

if (ID_Company != "all") {
    requests = requests.Where(x=>x.ID_Company == ID_Company );
}

request = requests .OrderByDescending(x=>.RequestDate).ToList();
```